# Font changed when generate pdf with wkhtmltopdf on online server

Tags: php, html, css, wkhtmltopdf

I created pdf with wkhtml2pdf with Arial font, while generate on local does not matter. But at the time of generating in online, font changed to be Times New Roman.

**Code CSS**

```
 .div1 {
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 10px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
.div1 {
font-family: Arial!important;
font-size: 10px;
padding-left: 5px;
padding-top: 0px;
}
```

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

kind late, but i use this and works fine...

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <style>
  body{
    font-family:Arial, sans-serif;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hi!</h1>
</body>
```

the key is in meta charset inside the head tag